# Confusion regarding the output of threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently working with python v.2.7 on windows 8.

My programme is using threads. I am providing a name to these threads during their creation. The first thread is named `First-Thread` and second one is named `Second-Thread`. The threads execute a method named as `getData()` that does the following:

- makes the current thread to sleep for some time
- calls the `compareValues()`
- retrieve the information from the `compareValues`() and adds them to a
  list called `myList`

The `compareValues()` does the following:

- generates a random number
- checks if it is less than 5 or if it is greater than or equal to 5
  and yields the result along with the current thread's name

I save the results of these threads to a list named as `myList` and then finally print this `myList`.

**Problem**: Why I never see the `Second-Thread` in `myList`? I don't understand this behavior. Please try to execute this code to see the output in order to understand my problem.

**Code**:

```
import time
from random import randrange
import threading

myList = []
def getData(i):
        print "Sleep for %d"%i
        time.sleep(i)
        data = compareValues()
        for d in list(data):
            myList.append(d)

def compareValues():
        number = randrange(10)
        if number >= 5:
             yield "%s: Greater than or equal to 5: %d  "%(t.name, number)
        else:
             yield "%s: Less than 5: %d  "%(t.name, number)

threadList = []
wait = randrange(10)+1
t = threading.Thread(name = 'First-Thread', target = getData, args=(wait,))
threadList.append(t)
t.start()
wait = randrange(3)+1
t = threading.Thread(name = 'Second-Thread', target = getData, args=(wait,))
threadList.append(t)
t.start()
for t in threadList:
    t.join()
print
print "The final list"
print myList
```

**Sample output**:

```
Sleep for 4Sleep for 1

The final list
['First-Thread: Greater than or equal to 5: 7  ', 'First-Thread: Greater than or equal to 5: 8  ']
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compareValues():
        number = randrange(10)
        if number >= 5:
             yield "%s: Greater than or equal to 5: %d  "%(t.name, number)
        else:
             yield "%s: Less than 5: %d  "%(t.name, number)
```

In the body of `compareValues` the code refers to `t.name`. By the time `compareValues()` gets called by the threads, `t`, which is looked up according to the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) and found in the **global scope**, references the first thread because the `t.join()` is waiting on the first thread. `t.name` thus has the value `First-Thread`.

To get the current thread name, use `threading.current_thread().name`:

```
def compareValues():
        number = randrange(10)
        name = threading.current_thread().name
        if number >= 5:
             yield "%s: Greater than or equal to 5: %d  "%(name, number)
        else:
             yield "%s: Less than 5: %d  "%(name, number)
```

Then you will get output like

```
Sleep for 4
Sleep for 2

The final list
['Second-Thread: Less than 5: 3  ', 'First-Thread: Greater than or equal to 5: 5  ']
```

Comment: +1 This is what I call a perfect explanation. Thanks.